# Get Variables name by it's value in Dart Lang

Tags: dart, dart-html

For Example, I have a variable like this.

```
var fooBar = 12;
```

I want a something like this in Dart lang.

```
print_var_name(fooBar);
```

which prints:

```
fooBar
```

How can I achieve that? Is this even possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no such thing in Dart for the web or for Flutter.
Reflection can do that, but reflection is only supported in the server VM because it hurts tree-shaking.

You need to write code for that manually or use code generation where you need that.

**An example:**

```dart
class SomeClass {
  String foo = 'abc';
  int bar = 12;

  dynamic operator [](String name) {
    switch(name) {
      case 'foo': return foo;
      case 'bar': return bar;
      default: throw 'no such property: "$name"';
    }
  }
}

main() {
  var some = SomeClass();
  print(some['foo']);
  print(some['bar']); 
}
```

**output:**

```
abc
123
```

Comment: Thank you for letting me know that.

Comment: Forgot to mention, there is https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/reflectable with a Flutter example in https://github.com/eernstg/reflectable-flutter