# How can I print the variable name itself in dart?

Tags: c++, dart, debugging

I used to do this CPP, to debug my code quickly.

**code.cpp:**

```cpp
#define bug(x) cout << #x << ": " << x << '\n'

int main() {
    int a = 5;
    bug(a);

    int b = 3;
    bug(b);
    
    return 0;
}
```

**output:**

```
a: 5
b: 3
```

what this does is, it print the variable name along with it's value dynamically.

now I am trying to make something like this in dart, but couldn't find anything.

can such thing be even done in dart ?? btw, if you a better debug practice, please let me know :)

I searched on StackOverflow, but couldn't find anything:

- [Get Variables name by it's value in Dart Lang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53737110/get-variables-name-by-its-value-in-dart-lang):

  - the answer mentioned only prints the value from a map, but what I am asking is to print the variable name itself (`a`, `b`) along their value (`5`, `3`)
  - and using `reflectable` prints the variable name by passing value, but I simply want to print variable name by passing variable itself.

I even asked ChatGPT, but this is what it came up with:

```dart
void bug(var x) {
  print('$x: ${x.toString()}');
}

void main() {
  int x = 5;
  bug(x);
}
```

not useful at all :facepalm:, as this will print `5: 5`.

Comment: @MendelG, the approach mentioned it this answer is a manual approach, I have to maintain the list of variables by myself. which will become a bit tedious.

Comment: ChatGPT literally has no idea what it's talking about. As a source for facts, it's less trustworthy than a random web search.

Comment: Don't rely on printing debug output, it will change the behavior (timing) of your code. Instead write unit tests and use a debugger to find your problems. (In other words you don't want your debug code to be different from your release code)

Comment: This is not possible without metaprogramming (such as by using a preprocessor or by using code generation).

Comment: @molbdnilo, exactly. but I like to test it's limit, so for those problems which I am unable to find answer on the web, I turn to ChatGPT. always fascinated by what it comes up with.

Comment: @PepijnKramer okay, understood your point. will change my habit. thanks mate :)

Comment: @jamesdlin I see, then I'll leave it, and try to apply what said.