# How to get the variable name as String value in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

`String foodIcon = 'assets/icons/expense/food.png';`
I want to receive the foodIcon variable name as a String value ('foodIcon')

I saw a StackOverflow answer for a similar question that says to use a map or dictionary.

Is there any method to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This can not be achieved in dart, it will create problems for tree shaking.

You can refer [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53737110/get-variables-name-by-its-value-in-dart-lang) as well